# How do I turn off snaplines in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

How do you turn off those blue guide lines when working on an ASP.NET form in VS 2008?. You used to be able to just drag absolute controls around. Now, I'm fighting with the designer which won't let me put things where I want to put them!

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 8):

Try holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while dragging - this will temporarily disable all snaplines.

If you want to permanently disable them then go to *Tools* > *Options* > *HTML Designer* > *CSS Styling* and uncheck *Change positioning to absolute...* (it is the last checkbox in the list).

Answer (score 1):

Actually - they key change is that to drag a control around in VS2008, you drag the white tab **ABOVE** the control, not the control itself. If you drag the control of the window, you're changing the parent.

http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2008/03/05/absolute-and-relative-positioning-in-visual-studio-2008-web-designer.aspx

This is a stubtle change to the way it worked in VS2005.

But the reminder about using the ALT key to turn off grid/snapping as well is useful as well.

I googled so many times to try and find this!

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the position attribute on a div to `position: absolute` will allow you to drag it around.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is one of the top results in a google search...for Visual studio 2019 pressing CTRL while moving will turn off the snap lines.

Comment: Add answer regarding VS 2008 only

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30705998)